# Phoenix / Elixir usage of cores, Cant max them

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have created a simple function that should broadcast random messages to a channel. I've tried to spawn 4-16 processes but the CPU Usage wont go over 200%. I have 8 cores.

```
defmodule Example do

  def listen do
    receive do
      {:ok, "rush"} ->
        sample_text = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux", "quuz"]
        h = Enum.take_random(sample_text, 1)
        MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast("topic", "message:new", %{body: Enum.at(h, 0, :default)})
    end

    listen()
  end
end

max = 16
list = Enum.flat_map (1..max), fn _ ->
  [spawn(Example, :listen, [])]
end

elem(:timer.tc(fn -> (1..1000000)|> Enum.each(fn x ->
  send Enum.at(list, rem(x, (max-1)), :default), {:ok, "rush"}
end)end, []),0) / 1000000
```

Is this connected to my SSD and that's the bottleneck or why cant I max the CPU usage?

This is what I'm getting when booting up phoenix.

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
```

Comment: Have you tried spawning multiple sender processes as well?

Comment: @Dogbert I have not. Maybe that would do it?

Comment: @Dogbert See my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it didnt use all cpus was because I defined the modules directly in the console instead of compiling them. Once I did that it did work out as expected :)